# All products have randomly jumbled catagories, is this a known issue is 1.7.0.2?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category

For some reason most of our products have seemed to changed categories in random ways. Is there any known issue of products changing catagories randomly?

Comment: explain your Question

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, there is no such problems exist with Magento. But this can be occured if,

1. There are some bad extensions which customize catalog part of your system
2. Cache issues.
3. Catalog configurations that you have done through backend side.

**1.Bad Extensions**

You need to find out any bad customization related to catalog which is done by any custom extension. If yes, then shoot them down.

Finding such extensions/modules is purely a techinical job. You may need help from an experienced Magento developer in this case.

**2. Cache Problems**

It may occur due to cache issue. Remove all cache from your system. Remove `var/cache` folder and reload the page again.

**3. Catalog Configurations**

These are not issues. I am just going to point out some conditions which can "replicate" same behavior in your system

a. If you put a product in multiple categories, then that product will be displayed in those categories.

b. If a product belong to a layered category, then that layered category normally show all the products which comes under it's child categories.

c. etc etc.

There may be more such catalog configurations which can show a product in several places in your Magento instance.

So go and inspect your site based on these points and find out the real reason behind it. Good luck.